# What Kind of investments should a new person in money should start with first?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing

I am thinking about entering the world of money and what should a first time investor should do to get a idea of what they are doing?

Comment: Search this site with the words first time investor. You will find 475 results.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Many good questions were already asked and answered, and we close the new duplicate questions, inviting you to read the older Q&A. I hope you read that answer, and visit again.

Comment: Investments in books about investing.

Comment: By very simple books offline " Investing for Dummies" etc. There are a lot of such guides that are being sold under the "XYZ" for dummies. The explanation in such books is very simple. Then you can move to internet. Idea is to not get bogged down all the content you see on internet